# Entries on the left side bar does not show automatically in dolphin file manager

Tags: dolphin

I use mx linux kde version and mistakenly, I clicked on hide entries on the left side bar of the dolphin file manager. Now each time I click on dolphin, the entries on the left side bar does not show up automatically, I need to click show all entries manually each time I start the application. This is bothering me a lot. Is there any way to sort out this minor issue?

Comment: After clicking "Show hidden places" you should be able to right-click on the grayed-out entries and deselect the "Hide" (or "Hide Section ...") checkbox.

Comment: thanks. it worked.